# RFC7807 Implementation Apprach

Tags: asp.net-core

The first I don't know is RFC7807 old or not.  When I using ASP.Net core to write API that the Microsoft recommend to use ValidationProblem to return fail.  So I try to read this https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7807#section-3.2 to learn what is this.  I know the goal is addition information for status code not is 200.  The following is my question.

1. This standard is for return non success to use?
2. If my API will return a batch of results that some result is success and some result is fail, so I cannot to use it for present, right?

Answer (score 0):

> This standard is for return non success to use?

The purpose of the specification is to define common error formats for applications that may need them. Therefore, it can be understood that it is used for the Api when returning failure.

> If my API will return a batch of results that some result is success
> and some result is fail, so I cannot to use it for present, right?

RFC 7807 make possible to support multiple errors thanks to extensions as can happen in validation use-cases: a response report the reference and reason of the different parts of the request document that offend some business rules.

You can refer to the explanation in [this article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/rfc-7807-error-handling-standard-apis-david-rold%C3%A1n-mart%C3%ADnez) and the corresponding response example to have a better understanding of it. If you want to use `ProblemDetails` Class when designing Api, you can refer to [this example](https://github.com/CodeMazeBlog/problemdetails-class-aspnetcore) for design, which will be very useful.

Comment: May I know which common API call supported it? eg. Github API, Facebook or Google?

Comment: RFC7807 is for Http response, theoretically speaking, these should all apply.